# Send a DELETE request to serverTokenEndpoint using ember-simple-auth

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-simple-auth

I can set a custom endpoint for ember-simple-auth to obtain tokens. It sends an HTTP POST request to the custom endpoint.

```
export default OAuth2PasswordGrant.extend({
    serverTokenEndpoint:'/tokens'
});
```

I'd like to add a custom invalidate method that sends a DELETE to `/tokens` as well.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    session: Ember.inject.service('session'),

    actions: {
        logout() {  
            this.get('session').invalidate();

            // DELETE to /tokens
        }
    }
});
```

Is this possible using an ember-simple-auth method? I can't see it working with ember data because there is no `token` model created in the first place. Or can this only be done with `Ember.$.ajax` or something like it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just implement `invalidate` in your custom authenticator and make the request with `Ember.$.ajax`.